# Programmatically retrieve an OS X disk partition UUID

Tags: macos, uuid, volume, diskarbitration

I have a path to a partition. How can I retrieve UUID of that partition programatically without using terminal commands? An example will be more helpful.

Comment: This might help you.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329925/extracting-mac-addresses-from-uuids)

Comment: @iammilind : That's MAC, a 48 bit network address. This seems to be Apple Mac OSX.

Comment: Your question says **partition** but it's tagged with **volume**.  The UUID of a partition is different from the UUID of the "volume" that is in that partition.  For example, using the answer of @user57368 :
`$ diskutil info /Volumes/Mulch | grep UUID`
`   Volume UUID:              E1EAC65D-47A2-3AB3-BCE5-BA25FD2C6A30`
`   Disk / Partition UUID:    E24032E3-DC36-470E-86B9-C9664026F8EC`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Disk Arbitration framework ([Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/index.html)). There is also a good summary at this [blog](http://sutes.co.uk/2008/10/disk-arbitration.html) by Chris Suter.

You can get the UUID by using the kDADiskDescriptionMediaUUIDKey. Aaron Burghardt described it well in this mailing list [thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.macosx.devel/21192). Here is a quote from that link:

> Once you have the DADisk, use DADiskCopyDescription to get a dictionary of properties, in which you will
>   find the UUID with the key kDADiskDescriptionMediaUUIDKey (see DADisk.h for other keys that may be of
>   interest). Note, a DADisk is a wrapper around an IOMedia object and the description dictionary
>   corresponds directly to the properties in the IOMedia object.  Also, CFShow() is useful for printing the
>   description dictionary to the console.

Answer (score 8):

`$ diskutil info / | grep UUID`

Running this from C is left as an exercise for the reader.

If you want a partition other than the root, you can specify the mount point or device name (eg. disk0s2) in place of `/`.

Comment: Thank you for the terminal command. Can u tell me how(is there a way) to do that only using c or c++ without using terminal commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to use **polkit**

Download the DiskWatcher.h and .m from 
http://polkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FileSystem/DiskWatcher.h
http://polkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FileSystem/DiskWatcher.m

Add it to your project (It has no ARC so add -fno-objc-arc flag if you use ARC)

Add DiskArbiratation framework
You can use

```
+ (NSString*) diskIdentifierForPath:(NSString*)path;

NSString *UUID1 = [DiskWatcher diskIdentifierForPath:@"/Volumes/Backup900GB"];
```